# Create custom installation for sql express

Tags: c#, windows, installation

I’m creating a custom setup to deploy my application and I need to silent installation of SQL Express 2008. Everything works fine except bellows:

1. I need to illustrate installation progress to user and I don’t know how I can do!
2. Sometimes (depends on computer which run setup) I've got a long gap time between buffering/copying and installing, So how can I avoid user to cancel or re-run setup ?
3. How can I determine setup has been completed? (in a simple solution I check SQL instance but the instance has been finished some earlier)
   I was wondering if you guide how can I solve my problems or where can I find some same solutions.
   Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [`/QS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#Install) command line switch.
2. It depends on how your deployment process is organized.
3. The setup process was exited with error code 0.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read [Install SQL Server 2012 from the Command Prompt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx)?

> I need to illustrate installation progress to user

Use `/QS`: *When installing through the command prompt, SQL Server supports full quiet mode by using the /Q parameter, or Quiet Simple mode by using the /QS parameter. **The /QS switch only shows progress**, does not accept any input, and displays no error messages if encountered. The /QS parameter is only supported when /Action=install is specified.*

> So how can I avoid user to cancel...

Use `/QS`: *... The /QS switch only shows progress, **does not accept any input** ...*

> How can I determine setup has been completed

Wait for the setup to finish. How this is accomplished depends on how you launch the installer. From a script use [`start /wait`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true). From C# use [`Process.WaitForExit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit.aspx).

And yes, always install the latest SQL Express edition (now 2012, soon 2014). No reason to deploy a 6 years old out-of-support edition of a free program...